# I want to open a web view instead of Browser whenever I click link on my textView

Tags: browser, webview, hyperlink

I have a lot of input text that contains linked URL on the textview field. I just want to set to default whenever I clicked any link on the textview it will pop up the webView instead of the browser.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html

you can use this function from UITextViewDelegate:

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange{

  NSLog(@"URL %@",URL); // URL
  // pop webkit

  return NO;
  }

Comment: I want to apply all the text that contains URL and pop the web view. can u give me example?